# Difficulty Displaying an Untransformed and Transformed Graphics3D Object with Show

Tags: bugs, graphics3d, geometric-transform

## Update: This bug has been fixed

The bug has been fixed and the code below is working in `$Version=12.1.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)`.

## Original Question

I would like to illustrate a sequence of translations and rotations relative to the initial coordinate system simultaneously with multiple views using Manipulate.  I discovered that there are some transformations that do not play well together with untransformed objects with Show.

Are there some settings or perhaps a better structure to make the process more robust?

I am using *Mathematica* 12.0 ("12.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 6, 2019)") and I have the same results on two different Windows 7 and 10 machines.

Here is the code for my toy model.

```
(* Create Transform Function *)
(* Unit Vectors *)
{ex, ey, ez} = UnitVector[3, #] & /@ {1, 2, 3};
(* Set up Transform Function*)
m = IdentityMatrix[4];
(* Rotation Part *)
m[[1 ;; 3, 1 ;; 3]] = 
  RotationMatrix[c, ey].EulerMatrix[{a, b, 0}, {2, 1, 2}];
(* Translation Part *)
m[[1 ;; 3, -1]] = {r Cos[-a], y, r Sin[-a]};
transform[a_, b_, c_, r_, y_] = TransformationFunction[m];
(* Create base graphics for axes and reference geo *)
axes = {Red, Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {#, 0, 0}}], Green, 
    Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, #, 0}}], Blue, 
    Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, #}}]} &;
sphereaxes = {Dashed}~Join~axes[#]~
    Join~{White, Specularity[White, 50], Opacity[0.1], 
     Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, #]} &;
cyl = {White, Specularity[White, 50], Opacity[0.1], 
   Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}}, 1]};
(* Scene objects *)
refgr = Graphics3D[axes[1/4]~Join~cyl, Boxed -> False, 
   ViewProjection -> "Orthographic"];
movgeo = sphereaxes[1/3];
```

The Manipulate code:

```
(* Create Slider Model *)
Manipulate[
 With[{
   movgeotr = 
    Graphics3D@
     GeometricTransformation[movgeo, transform[a, b, c, x, y]]},
  GraphicsGrid[{
    {Show[{refgr, movgeotr}, ViewPoint -> Back, 
      ViewVertical -> {0, 0, -1}],
     Show[{refgr, movgeotr}, ViewPoint -> {0, 0, Infinity}]},
    {Show[{refgr, movgeotr}, ViewPoint -> {-Infinity, 0, 0}, 
      ViewVertical -> {-1, 1, 0}],
     Show[{refgr, movgeotr}, 
      ViewPoint -> {Infinity, Infinity, Infinity}, 
      ViewVertical -> {0, 1, 0}]}
    }, Dividers -> Center, Frame -> All, Spacings -> Scaled[0.25], 
   ImageSize -> Medium]
  ],
 {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {a, 0, 360 Degree}, {b, 0, 180 Degree}, {c, 0, 
  360 Degree}]
```

When I execute the Manipulate expression, there are certain conditions that cause most views to be poorly displayed as shown below:

[image: Manipulate Animation]

A minimal case to produce the effect is shown below:

```
Graphics3D@GeometricTransformation[movgeo, transform[0, 0, 0, 0.4, 0]]
Show[{refgr, 
  Graphics3D@
   GeometricTransformation[movgeo, transform[0, 0, 0, 0.4, 0]]}, 
 ViewPoint -> {0, 0, Infinity}]
```

[image: Minimal Result]

The transformed object displays with Graphics3D, but will not display when combined with the untransformed object in Show.  Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: It might be a Windows specific issue. I don't see your issue in M12 on OSX.

Comment: @CarlWoll Thanks for checking that out on a different system!  At least the current approach should in principle work.  I have also submitted a request to Wolfram to get their opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that Show is not behaving as intended on at least Windows 7 and 10 (CASE:4260146).  I have found a work around that required 2 changes although I do not know how general the fix will be.

First, I found that if represented the cylinder with a RegionPlot3D or ContourPlot3D versus a Cylinder primitive, it will display over the range of parameters.  ContourPlot3D performs much better, presumably because there is no volume rendering taking place.

Second, I found the isometric view (the last view) did not like the Infinity specification for the ViewPoint so I replaced them with smaller values.

The adjusted code and Manipulate results are shown below.

```
(* Create Transform Function *)
(* Unit Vectors *)
{ex, ey, ez} = UnitVector[3, #] & /@ {1, 2, 3};
(* Set up Transform Function*)
m = IdentityMatrix[4];
(* Rotation Part *)
m[[1 ;; 3, 1 ;; 3]] = 
  RotationMatrix[c, ey].EulerMatrix[{a, b, 0}, {2, 1, 2}];
(* Translation Part *)
m[[1 ;; 3, -1]] = {r Cos[-a], y, r Sin[-a]};
transform[a_, b_, c_, r_, y_] = TransformationFunction[m];
(* Create base graphics for axes and reference geo *)
axes = {Red, Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {#, 0, 0}}], Green, 
    Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, #, 0}}], Blue, 
    Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, #}}]} &;
sphereaxes = {Dashed}~Join~axes[#]~
    Join~{White, Specularity[White, 50], Opacity[0.1], 
     Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, #]} &;
cyl = ContourPlot3D[x^2 + z^2 == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 2}, {z, -1, 1},
    Mesh -> None, 
   ContourStyle -> 
    Directive[Opacity[0.1], White, Specularity[White, 50]], 
   Boxed -> False, Axes -> False];
(* Scene objects *)
refgr = cyl;
movgeo = sphereaxes[1/3];
(* Create Slider Model *)
Manipulate[
 With[{
   movgeotr = 
    Graphics3D@
     GeometricTransformation[movgeo, transform[a, b, c, x, y]]},
  GraphicsGrid[{
    {Show[{refgr, movgeotr}, ViewPoint -> {0, Infinity, 0}, 
      ViewVertical -> {0, 0, -1}],
     Show[{refgr, movgeotr}, ViewPoint -> {0, 0, Infinity}]},
    {Show[{refgr, movgeotr}, ViewPoint -> {-Infinity, 0, 0}, 
      ViewVertical -> {-1, 1, 0}],
     Show[{refgr, movgeotr}, ViewPoint -> {5, 5, 5}, 
      ViewVertical -> {0, 1, 0}]}
    }, Dividers -> Center, Frame -> All, Spacings -> Scaled[0.25], 
   ImageSize -> Medium]
  ],
 {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {a, 0, 360 Degree}, {b, 0, 180 Degree}, {c, 0, 
  360 Degree}]
```

[image]