# Geometry3D objects as functions of parameters

Tags: graphics3d, simulation, rotation, image3d

I want to make a simulation of a rigid body with mathematica, but I want to use a Geometry3D object instead of a Graphics3D primitive.

Mainly I don't know how to rotate the 3D model, I know how to do it with graphs through for example:

```
GeometricTransformation[ring3,EulerMatrix[{alpha, beta, gamma}, {1, 2, 3}]]
```

Is there any way to rotate and translate the 3D model in such a way?

thankx in advance

Comment: Look up [`TransformedRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedRegion)

Comment: I find GeometricTransfomation following your suggestion,  I think it will do it, thank you!

Comment: Perhaps my question [198323](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/198323/61809) could give you some ideas on how to deal with transformations.

Answer (score 4):

You can transform a [`GraphicsComplex`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsComplex.html) too.  For example:

```
Manipulate[
 cow /. {GraphicsComplex[vtx_, args___] :> 
    GeometricTransformation[GraphicsComplex[vtx, args], 
     Dynamic[EulerMatrix[{α, β, γ}]]]}, \
{{α, 0}, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/32}, {{β, 0}, 0, 2 Pi, 
  Pi/32}, {{γ, 0}, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/32}, 
 Initialization :> {cow := ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Cow"}]}, 
 ControlPlacement -> Top]
```

[image: Cow rotation]

## Update: Extend Response to Comment

If you look at the `InputForm` of the example data, you can see the `GraphicsComplex`

```
Short[InputForm[ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Phobos"}]], 5]
(* \!\(
TagBox[
PaneBox["\<\"Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], \
GraphicsComplex[{{-1.3601044416427612, 9.545239448547363, \
0.0012262604432180524}, {-1.2952135801315308, 9.546309471130371, \
0.36269038915634155}, {-0.7759165167808533, 9.590052604675293, \
0.5633725523948669}, <<9405>>, {5.872391700744629, \
3.5175044536590576, 9.917975425720215}, {-11.840780258178711, \
2.7396738529205322, -4.5116286277771}}, <<2>>]}, Boxed -> False]\"\>"],
Short[#, 5]& ]\) *)
```

You can see that the `GraphicsComplex` contains a list of vertices or points and geometric entities that refer to the vertices by index.

You can use `Cases` to extract the `GraphicsComplex` by itself.

```
First@Cases[ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Phobos"}], _GraphicsComplex, 
  Infinity]
```

[image]

The geometric transform operates on the vertices only.  If you want to extract the vertices and the argument separately, you can use:

```
With[{gc = 
   First@Cases[
     ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Phobos"}], _GraphicsComplex, 
     Infinity]}, 
 gc /. {GraphicsComplex[vtx_, args___] :> {vtx, args}}]
```

[image: Vertex and Arguments]

Here is an example of how to rotate Phobos:

```
phobos = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Phobos"}];
With[{shape = phobos, a = 0, b = 0, c = 0}, 
 shape /. {GraphicsComplex[vtx_, args___] :> 
    GeometricTransformation[GraphicsComplex[vtx, args], 
     EulerMatrix[{a, b, c}]]}]
With[{shape = phobos, a = 10, b = 5, c = 6}, 
 shape /. {GraphicsComplex[vtx_, args___] :> 
    GeometricTransformation[GraphicsComplex[vtx, args], 
     EulerMatrix[{a, b, c}]]}]
```

[image: Phobos rotation]

## Update: Space Shuttle Request for Alex

```
Manipulate[
 spaceshuttle /. {GraphicsComplex[vtx_, args___] :> 
    GeometricTransformation[GraphicsComplex[vtx, args], 
     Dynamic[EulerMatrix[{α, β, γ}]]]}, \
{{α, 0}, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/32}, {{β, 0}, 0, 2 Pi, 
  Pi/32}, {{γ, 0}, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/32}, 
 Initialization :> {spaceshuttle := 
    ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "SpaceShuttle"}]}, 
 ControlPlacement -> Top]
```

[image: Space shuttle]

Comment: Good answer (+1). Could you replace image cow with "SpaceShuttle"?

Comment: @Gluoncito I put an extended response in my answer.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I added a Space Shuttle example.

Comment: @Tim Laska, I deleted my earlier comment  because I realized that GraphicsComplex was the "magic" word lacking when loading the 3D model. Your detailed response was very useful, thank you very much !